# Unable to locate the file while using ${user.dir} to avoid hardcoding in the @Config.Sources of the Owner library in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, properties-file, owner

I am unable to locate the file while using ${user.dir} to avoid hardcoding in the @Config.Sources annotation of the Owner library in Java to locate the property file.

Using the absolute path to locate the file works for me perfectly as shown below

```
@Config.Sources(value="C:\\Users\\username\\eclipse-workspace\\MWAFW\\src\\test\\resources\\FrameworkConfig.properties")
public interface FrameworkConfig extends Config {
    ...
}
```

However, If I use

```
@Config.Sources(value="${user.dir}\\src\\test\\resources\\FrameworkConfig.properties")
public interface FrameworkConfig extends Config {
    ...
}
```

or

```
@Config.Sources(value="${user.dir}/src/test/resources/FrameworkConfig.properties")
public interface FrameworkConfig extends Config {
    ...
}
```

does not locate the properties file.
Why is ${user.dir} not working for me in this case?

- I am using a maven-Java project on Intellij community edition

Answer (score 0):

You can try below steps to solve it

1. Print the value of ${user.dir} to the console or log file to verify that it resolves to the expected directory
2. using an absolute path to the property file

   ```
    @Config.Sources(value="/src/test/resources/FrameworkConfig.properties")
        public interface FrameworkConfig extends Config {
        }
   ```
3. In IntelliJ IDEA, you can set the working directory in the Run/Debug Configuration for your application try checking, make sure that the working directory is set correctly
4. Using classpath

   ```
    @Config.Sources(value="classpath:FrameworkConfig.properties")
    public interface FrameworkConfig extends Config {
       ...
    }
   ```